# Which one is correct, below is the transaction summary or below are the transactions summary?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct from this 2 sentences?

**Below is the transaction summary of your purchase**

or

**Below are the transactions summary of your purchase**

I will use it on a payment receipt that contains Customer Name, Email Address, Phone number, Item name, Quantity, Price, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a single summary, so both verb and noun should be in the singular:

> Below **is** the transaction summary of your purchase.

Comment: that's a typo, silly me, edited

Comment: No harm done here, but in the future if there's already an answer in place, be careful not to edit your question so that the answer becomes wrong. (I have updated my answer to be in accord with the new version of your question.)